# Mock DbSet SetupData configuration confusion

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am using the EntityFramework.Testing.Moq library to unit test my repositories but I have run into some confusion and can't find documentation anywhere. In the code example below I use the SetupData method of the previously mentioned library to create a mocked DbSet that can be used like a real one but just writes data to memory instead of the database.

The Method takes 2 parameters, the first being any data you want to preload into the DbSet, and the second being a predicate function representing the Find method of the DbSet. For single key tables I have gotten everything working using the code below though I don't really understand what magic is happening with the objects in the predicate Find function. My problem now is I have another table with a composite key so I don't know how to tweak the predicate function to account for the composite key. Any help is much appreciated.

```
var mockUserOrganizationRoleData = new List<UserOrganizationRole>();
UserOrganizationRoleDbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<UserOrganizationRole>>()
    .SetupData(mockUserOrganizationRoleData, objects => mockUserOrganizationRoleData.SingleOrDefault(d => d.UserOrganizationRoleId == (int)objects.First()));
```

Comment: _... to unit test my repositories_ - responsibility of repositories is reading, saving data to some datastore(database). So instead of mocking you can tests against actual database or, if possible, use in-memory databases. By mocking `DbSet` you will be forced to change your tests every time you refactor/optimize your queries even behaviour will not change

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make it work, but this is some kind of black magic because I have absolutely no clue what is actually happening here or how it works. Feel free to explain if anyone understand more than myself but this at least does what I want.

```
var mockUserSystemPreferenceData = new List<UserSystemPreference>();
UserSystemPreferenceDbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<UserSystemPreference>>()
    .SetupData(mockUserSystemPreferenceData, objects => mockUserSystemPreferenceData.SingleOrDefault(d => d.SystemPreferenceId == (int)objects.First() && d.UserId == (Guid)objects.First()));
```